# deliveryId owerflow for AtLeastOnceDelivery guaranty from akka persistence

Tags: akka, akka-persistence

I'm trying to implement some AtLeastOnceDelivery decorator for reliable messaging for different actors. So such decorator attempt to handle pretty intensive messaging and will share the lyfecycle with the application.

According to AtLeastOnceDelivery [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/persistence/AtLeastOnceDelivery.html) the deliveryId is a strictly monotonically increasing sequence number without gaps (long).

The question is: what will happen when the value is overflow the max long?
Does akka-persistence handle such case correctly?

Comment: A quick look at the source code tells me that there's nothing in place for handling the situation. I think that's because the wrap around is very unlikely. Scala Long max value is 9223372036854775807. To put this into perspective, even if you processed one billion messages each day, it would take 25269512 years until max long is reached.

Comment: @JaakkoPallari I think this is an answer. Please re-post it and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at [AtLeastOnceDelivery source code](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/8b5018ba21cf2651cb74fa7ef2b2bc2cea175bff/akka-persistence/src/main/scala/akka/persistence/AtLeastOnceDelivery.scala) tells me that there's nothing in place for handling `Long` overflow situations.

I believe the reason why there's no handling in place is because overflow is very unlikely. Scala `Long` maximum value is 9223372036854775807. To put this into perspective, even if you processed one billion messages each day, it would take 25269512 years until maximum value is reached.